# Parse XML with name namespaces PHP

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to parse XML to get "text" message:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <S:Body>
  <S:Fault xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
     <faultcode>S:Server</faultcode>
     <faultstring>Error saving JobsReport</faultstring>
     <detail>
        <ns2:ErrorMsg xmlns:ns2="http://www.testX.com.pl/wsdl/sdis-emm">
           <Error code="20" text="More than one row with the given identifier was found: 389, for class: ekt.bean.sdis.RepPerson" />
        </ns2:ErrorMsg>
     </detail>
  </S:Fault>
 </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

but `SimpleXMLElement()` and `simplexml_load_file()` returns only empty object. When I remove "S:" is better, but not ok.

`registerXPathNamespace` doesn't help.

Help, thx.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a Soap response. PHP 's own SoapClient object deals automatically with this XML and delivers objects as responses as described in the functions and types definitions of the webservice. Here 's a small illustrative example:

```
try {
    $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
    $response = $client->functionName($params);

    var_dump($response);
    // response would be an object with members as described by the webservice
} catch (SoapFault $e) {
    // prints error message
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

So for more comfort you should definitely take a look on SoapClient in the PHP manual. SoapClient handles all the XML stuff automatically so you will not get in touch with it.

If you still want to handle the XML requests and responses on yourself, you can do it with PHP 's own DomDocument object. Here 's a small illustrative example:

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xmlResponse);

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://www.testX.com.pl/wsdl/sdis-emm', 'Error') as $element) {
    echo $element->getAttribute('text');
}
```

This is the more complicated way, because SoapClient throws a SoapFault, if an error occurs, which you can easiely catch and do whatever you want with it.